# List Comprehension with Not In

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is a list comprehension but I'm not getting the result I expected. I'm writing a playing card game.

So I start with a list like this, that has 5 cards

```
card_numbers = [ 13, 4, 13, 11, 14 ]
```

the numbers represent cards, i.e. 13 represents a King, so theres a pair of kings in this hand.

I need to find out how many pairs appear in this list. There is 1 pair of kings, so I need
a list called `pairs` that contains a single element, 13, like so:

```
pairs = [ 13 ]
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
pairs = [ number for number in card_numbers if card_numbers.count(number) == 2 and number not in pairs ]
```

However, this gives me

```
pairs = [ 13, 13 ]
```

It's like the `not in` part isn't registering, I think because I'm trying to refer to the same list I'm creating with the comprehension. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `because I'm trying to refer to the same list I'm creating with the comprehension`—Yes, that.

Comment: Using `collections.Counter` would be a more efficient way to do this, I think.

Comment: This code is returning the proper result for me!! Are you sure you are running this code?

Answer (score 2):

This does quite literally what you need, is this what you're after?

```
from collections import Counter

card_numbers = [13, 4, 13, 11, 14]
card_counts = Counter(card_numbers)
print([card for card, count in card_counts.items() if count == 2])
```

Since it's become clear you want cards for all possible counts, something like this is straightforward:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

card_numbers = [13, 4, 13, 11, 14]
card_counts = defaultdict(list)
for card, count in Counter(card_numbers).items():
    card_counts[count].append(card)
print(card_counts)
```

Comment: Hi thanks everyone for responses. WangGang that code is what I was doing before, I was hoping a list comprehension would be more efficient. Grismar thanks for the idea, I tried implementing that but its actually a bit slower than doing what WangGang suggests, probbably because I can set "pairs, trips, and fours" in the same for loop. With Counter I need 3 list comprehensions, one for pairs, one for trips, and one for fours. This is apparently a bit slower then using a for loop and building all 3 inside the same for loop

Comment: @GeoffL How fast do you play cards so that speed is an issue? :-)

Comment: Hi. I'm not actually playing cards I'm trying to build a list of probabilities of winning various hands vs someone else, and there's a ton of possible combinations so I'm making a lookup table, and that table is going to take hours to build at the current execution rate

Comment: If you need all of them, you can simply go: `card_counts = dict(Counter(card_numbers))` and you're done - or you need to invert the dictionary, which is really simple to do as well. You should probably state your actual problem, instead of asking for specific solution that may not be the right one - this is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because you are trying to refer to the same list you are creating with the comprehension. A solution to this would be to use a for loop.

```
for number in card_numbers:
    if card_numbers.count(number) == 2 and number not in pairs:
        pairs.append(number)
```

Comment: Don't append back to pairs!! That is going to add after the values already in pairs!

Comment: No, it will not. If you run this program using `card_numbers = [ 13, 4, 13, 11, 14 ]`, then, `pairs = [13]`.

Comment: Thats not supposed to be the output - `pairs` is supposed to be `[]`, not `[13]`

Comment: No, pairs is supposed to be [13], please read the post again.

Comment: If you run OP's program (`pairs = [ number for number in card_numbers if card_numbers.count(number) == 2 and number not in pairs ]`) with the variables, I get `pairs = []`, not `pairs = [13]`. Also, I don't even know _why_ the OP's program doesn't work on his end, because it works perfectly fine on mine.

Comment: Try running the program. I have no idea _where_ you are getting this, but please tell me, as I want to know where.

Answer (score 1):

Try making it a `set` first, then you don't even need your check (and you save time by not counting duplicates again).

```
>>> [number for number in set(card_numbers) if card_numbers.count(number) == 2]
[13]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import a library (which you should), here is a solution:

```py
doubles = [s for s in set(card_numbers) if sum([c == s for c in card_numbers]) == 2]
```